# custom permalink for pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am trying to add custom permalink for pagination on wordpress

I tried so far

```
function my_pagenum_link( $link ) { 
    $link = preg_replace( '~/news-(\d+)/?~', '', $link );
    return preg_replace( '~/page/(\d+)/?~', '/news-\1', $link );
}
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'my_pagenum_link' );
```

it giving me link I want like:

http://exmaple.com/category/news-2

but when I am opening the link, it is redirecting to :

http://exmaple.com/category/news-2/page/2

Please suggest how I can stop wordpress to redirect

Comment: I thinks you can achieve it by adding some rewrite rules.

Comment: I need for my custom post :
add_rewrite_rule('up-news/news-([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=up-news&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');

but it is still redirecting

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by adding

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical','custom_disable_redirect_canonical');
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) { 
    return false;
}
```